# Check if Variables Are Set

Tags: php

What is the most efficient way of checking whether POST variables have been set or not?

Eg, I am collecting 10 variables from **Page 1**, if they are set I would like to store that data on **Page 2**. If not, I would like to assign '*not available*'.

I am currently using `if !empty`, however it seems like there must be an easier/more efficient method, I'm quite new to php so any advice is appreciated.

Example code;

```
if (!empty($_POST["book"])) {
    $book= $_POST['book'];    
}else{  
    $book= 'not available';
}

if (!empty($_POST["author"])) {
    $author = $_POST['author'];    
}else{  
    $author= 'not available';
}

if (!empty($_POST["subtitle"])) {
    $subtitle= $_POST['subtitle'];   
}else{  
    $subtitle= 'not available';
}

etc...
etc...
etc...
```

Comment: Do you know isset function? But be aware that a variable can be set and empty at the same time: $a="" is empty and set

Comment: @Serpes yes, however it's the same principal is it not?

Comment: They give you diferent results as I've said before

Comment: $book = isset($_POST['book']) && !empty($_POST['book']) ? $_POST['book'] : 'Not available';

Comment: You should be able to perf test these yourself to find out what the efficiency is.

Comment: @JA `isset && !empty` is redundant nonsense. Use either or.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a loop and variable-variables.

```
$fields = array('author', 'book', 'subtitle', ....);
foreach($fields as $field) {
   if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
      $$field = $_POST[$field]; // variable variable - ugly, but gets the job done
   } else {
      $$field = 'not available';
   }
}
```

Comment: Because you have the `$fields` array, you are restricting your loop to expected entries, therefore avoiding potential issues from bad requests. +1

Comment: yes, but OP said "SET", not "not empty". empty() is a moronic function anyways. empty(0) is true - which makes any code dealing with inventory/money/numbers vulnerable to false negatives. should've been called "is_castable_to_false()" instead.

Comment: I think OP wait some more, than empty string for his `$book` or `$author` =)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need @Marc B - will test and get back to you, thanks +1

Comment: I'd rather use array here (instead of `$$`), but it's probably just me. )

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use this helper function:

```
function defa($array, $key, $default){
    if(isset($array[$key])){
        return $array[$key];
    }else{
        return $default;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$book = defa($_POST, 'book', 'Not available');
```

Or, you can simplify if you are only using the $_POST array:

```
function post_defa($key, $default){
    if(isset($_POST[$key])){
        return $_POST[$key];
    }else{
        return $default;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$book = post_defa('book', 'Not available');
```