# How to check if at least one variable's value is set

Tags: php

I am trying to code with php to check if at least one variable value is set.

### Codes

```
$myshop = '';
$mycar = '';
$mybag = 'blue';
$myshirt = '';    

//now check if at least one variable's value is set

if(isset(var))
{
   $style = 1;
}
else{
   $style = 0;
}
```

Is there something can be done like taking these variables in an array then check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Variables Are Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109828/check-if-variables-are-set)

Answer (score 3):

Since the variables are either assigned blank or some alphabets you don't need to use any function.

Just use the variable separated by the logical OR operator `||`. Referring to the docs: [PHP Docs: logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

```
if ($myshop || $mycar || $mybag || $myshirt) {
   $style = 1;
} else {
   $style = 0;
}
```

Comment: All of these variables will be set with a blank result. Checking to see if they're empty or don't == '' would be better

Comment: Using only the variable returns false if it is an empty string `''`, but not `' '`, returns false if the variable is an empty array or is `null`

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to make sure that it has a value and not an empty string, use `!empty()`

```
$myshop = '';
$mycar = '';
$mybag = 'blue';
$myshirt = '';

if(!empty($myshop) || !empty($mycar) || !empty($mybag) || !empty($myshirt))
```

Comment: No. `isset` just checks to see if the variable exists. `!empty` checks to see if the variable exists and contains a truthy value, i.e. not null, 0, false, or an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
if(strlen($myshop . $mycar . $mybag . $myshirt) > 0) {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: only works with strings, which is kind of a problem if one of the variables suddenly is an array or an object

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$style=2;

$check=array("myshop","mycar","mybag","myshirt");
foreach ($check as $value) {
    if(isset($$value)){
        $style=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('myshop' => '','mycar' => '','mybag' => 'blue','myshirt' => '' );

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($value)){
       $style = true;
    }else{
       $style = false;
    }
}
```